# Angular UI Router not loading tempates or controllers when URL changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Although this question has been asked before, none of the answers seem to work for me.

My AngularJs application looks like this:
[image]

App & Config:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular
.module('app', [
    //'ngRoute',
    'ngResource',
    //'ngMessages',

    'ui.bootstrap',
    //'ngCookies',
    'dialogs.main',
    'ui.router',
    'templates'

]);


app.config(['$httpProvider', '$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($httpProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
    {

        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/profile');

        $stateProvider

            .state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                template: 'my profile',
                controller: function($scope){
                    alert(123);
                }
            })

            // nested list with custom controller
            .state('profile.education', {
                url: '/education',
                template: 'About my education',
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.dogs = ['Bernese', 'Husky', 'Goldendoodle'];
                }
            })

            // nested list with just some random string data
            .state('profile.personal-detail', {
                url: '/person-detail',
                template: 'My personal details'
            });

        if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        };

    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
    <p>This page demonstrates <span class="text-danger">nested</span> views.</p>

    <a ui-sref="profile" class="btn btn-primary">home</a>
    <a ui-sref="profile.education" class="btn btn-warning">education</a>
    <a ui-sref="profile.personal-detail" class="btn btn-danger">personal detail</a>
</div>

<div ui-view></div>
```

Issue:
When I load `http://laravel.dev/profile` in my browser, the view is updated with `my profile` and also dialog box with message "123" pops out, which means the template and controllers are loaded.

However, when I click the `education` button or `personal detail` button the URL changes **but neither the view is updated or the controller called**

What am I missing? I have already spent 4 hours on this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have <ui-view> in your template (profile page)? You need a view for each nest you make, if you have second level nesting, you need 2 views - 1 for first level, and one for second level, which is being rendered in first.

Comment: @Valdas hmm.. that makes sense, but am using this `template: 'my profile',` and not using `templateUrl`

Comment: You still can do `template: 'my profile<ui-view></ui-view>',`

Comment: @Valdas thanks a lot. Its working as expected however, when I click `<a ui-sref="profile" class="btn btn-primary">home</a>` the view is not updated with homepage template

Comment: @Valdas in state('profile') I have this ` 'my profile<ui-view></ui-view>'`, when I click education the content is appended to `profile` state

Comment: @Valdas my app now looks like this: http://pastebin.com/Vdnx3Zmk, everything is working as expected but am wondering if doing somethig like this is wrong `.state('profile', {
                    url: '/profile',
                    template: '<ui-view>Hello world, {{name}}</ui-view>',
                    controller: function($scope){
                        $scope.name = 'digitlimit';
                    }
                })`

Answer (score 0):

Your Profile Url is http://localhost:9000/#/profile

Your profile.education url is http://localhost:9000/#/profile/education

This url matches the first state provided i.e.
  .state('profile', .........)

Similarly Your second Url matches with this url.
Thats Why only first stated is called evertime.

When you are referencing a sub state like profile.something
Do this

```
.state('profile', {
                url: '/profile',
                template: '<a ui-sref="profile.education" class="btn btn-warning">education</a><a ui-sref="profile.personal-detail" class="btn btn-danger">personal detail</a><ui-view></ui-view>',
                controller: function($scope){

                }
            })
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, based on @Valdas comments everything is working except that when I click `<a ui-sref="profile" class="btn btn-primary">home</a>` the view becomes blank

Comment: Thats beacause when you click on "profile" it takes you to profile state template: 'my profile<ui-view></ui-view>' 
ui-view is null by default